# hidden error while deploying website to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

A few days ago I added a schema file to my website folder so I could use MongoDB with the website. On the surface everything has worked fine but when I deployed the website to Heroku I get the next lines of error on the logs:

```
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698455+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698560+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698560+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698560+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './../models/anime
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698561+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698561+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/watch.js
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698561+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698563+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698577+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-06-04T07:14:38.698577+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/routes/watch.js', '/app/app.js']
```

Comment: That error message is incomplete so we can't really see which module is not being found (at minimum, it is missing a `'`). Did the site work before you added the schema file? Or was this the first time you tried to deploy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.